# Problem with scapy summary function in python

Tags: python, scapy

I've imported the scapy module in my python code (arp-spoofer) and when i use the packet.show()/packet.summary() function the terminal return me this error:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arp-spoofer.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(packet.show())
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1261, in show
    return self._show_or_dump(dump, indent, lvl, label_lvl)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1235, in _show_or_dump
    reprval = f.i2repr(self, fvalue)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 376, in i2repr
    return fld.i2repr(pkt, val)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 502, in i2repr
    x = self.i2h(pkt, x)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 136, in i2h
    iff = self.getif(pkt)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 132, in <lambda>
    self.getif = (lambda pkt: pkt.route()[0]) if getif is None else getif
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 400, in route
    fld, dst = fld._find_fld_pkt_val(self, dst)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 313, in _find_fld_pkt_val
    if val == dflts_pkt[self.name] and self.name not in pkt.fields:
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 133, in __eq__
    p2, nm2 = self._parse_net(other)
  File "/home/baloo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 99, in _parse_net
    tmp = net.split('/') + ["32"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Code:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

victim_ip = ""
victim_mac_address  = ""
router_ip  = ""

packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=victim_ip, hwdst=victim_mac_address, psrc=router_ip)
print(packet.show())
print(packet.summary())
```

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you enter into the scapy prompt with `$ scapy`?

Comment: I am seeing that the code as stated *does work* in the Python3.7 and Scapy prompts. It's not going to be sent anywhere, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need the IPs to be valid.
If you don't want to set them yourself, don't specify them and Scapy will take the default.

Comment: Can you provide more infos then? What did you try ? What means "It doesn't work"?! Please ask a clear and precise question. The code you posted earlier is jammed because you set IPs that are "". That's not what I call a valid IP but rather an empty string !

Comment: I put the right IPs bbut when I try to run the program it gives me this error, I tried also with python2 and python3

Comment: Can you give which IPs?

Comment: @Cukic0d - perfect comment. C0bra - you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58454573/edit) your question so that it's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with *all* pertinent details so that we don't need to guess the problem :)